# webview_flutter, new window pop up not working in IOS platform

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview, webview-flutter

when i click on a button in my webview it opens a new window pop up in web , it renders in Android devices but in IOS it gives me 'about:blank' in url and shows blank screen, i have tried different packages still this issue exists (webview_flutter,inappwebview)

while the pop up should render i get url as "about:blank" in IOS

i have tried webview_flutter,inappwebview these two packages and added all properties in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

this is my code for web view

```
 @riverpod
 WebViewController webViewController(
 WebViewControllerRef ref, {
 required String url,
 TabController? tabController,
 bool isYodlee = false,
 bool isFromSubcritionPayment = false,
 String? currentPlaneCode,
 }) {
 bool loaderStarted = false;
 const params = PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
 final WebViewController controller =
 WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);
 controller
 ..setBackgroundColor(UIColors.backgroundPrimary)
 ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
 ..setNavigationDelegate(
  NavigationDelegate(
    onProgress: (progress) {
      printLog('loading progress $progress%');
      if (!loaderStarted) {
        ref.read(loaderStateProvider.notifier).showLoader();
        loaderStarted = true;
      }
      if (progress == 100) {
        ref.read(loaderStateProvider.notifier).hideLoader();
        loaderStarted = false;
      }
    },
    onPageStarted: (String pageUrl) async {
      if (pageUrl.startsWith(SubscriptionConstants.successPage)) {
        ref.read(loaderStateProvider.notifier).hideLoader();
        if (isFromSubcritionPayment) {
          popUntilPath(currentContext, const 
 SubscriptionPurchaseSuccess());
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(currentContext);
          await cAlertDialog<void>(
            context: currentContext,
            title: Text(
              
 localization(currentContext).subscriptions.cardUpdateTitle,
            ),
            content: Text(
              
 localization(currentContext).subscriptions.cardUpdateContent,
            ),
          );
        }
        ref
          ..invalidate(aliveCurrentSubscriptionServiceProvider)
          ..invalidate(billIntervalUnitProvider)
          ..invalidate(nextPlanProvider);
      } else {
        ref.read(loaderStateProvider.notifier).showLoader();
      }
    },
    onPageFinished: (String url) async {
      ref.read(loaderStateProvider.notifier).hideLoader();
      // For yodlee to receive message
      if (isYodlee) {
        await controller
            .runJavaScript(BankConstants.yodleeAccountFetchScript);
      }
    },
    onWebResourceError: (error) {
      ref.read(loaderStateProvider.notifier).hideLoader();
      cAlertDialog<void>(
        context: currentContext,
        content: const Text('Failed to load the page!'),
      );
      currentContext.pop();
      printLog(error.description);
    },
  ),
 )
 ..addJavaScriptChannel(
  'Message',
  onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
    // take the message and proceed to step 2 for yodlee
    if (isYodlee) {
      final data = YodleeWebResponse.fromJson(
        json.decode(message.message.replaceAll(r'\', '')) as JsonMap,
      );
      ref
          .read(newUnlinkedAccountsProvider.notifier)
          .getBankData(data)
          .then((value) {
        if (tabController != null) {
          tabController.animateTo(1);
        }
      });
    }
   },
   )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));
 return controller;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
        return NavigationDecision.navigate; //this work for me 
      },
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: i have tried this but did not work for me!